# how to determine failure in ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, mootools

I'm working with Mootools to develop a simple ajax-y page that does some manipulation with db records using PHP as the backend.

I'm submitting the ajax request to a PHP page that calls a function and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` if the record was able to be updated/deleted or not.

However, it seems like the mootools `onSuccess` event is fired anytime the server returns a 200 status, regardless of the value returned (eg. `FALSE` is still assumed to be a success).

How do I use onSuccess in a meaningful way, short of returning a 40x error code or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personaly, I feel that using the HTTP status codes to indicate the success/failure of whatever was supposed to happen on the server is incorrect. Everything about the HTTP call itself worked perfectly - the fact that the server was unable to complete the request doesn't mean the HTTP request failed.

It's like driving to the store to buy something, only to find it's out of stock. Returning an HTTP 404, to me, would imply that the store itself was gone. Yet, you've successfully driven to the store, walked inside, walked back out, drove home.

So, use a JSON data structure to indicate the results of the requested transaction, which you can check for in your client-side code:

```
$results = array()
$results['success'] = false;
$results['failure_code'] = XXX; // some code meaningful to your app
$results['failure_message'] = 'Something dun gone blowed up, pa!';
echo json_encode($results);
```

Then in your Moo code:

```
if (!results['success']) {
   alert("AJAX call failed: " + results['failure_message']);
}
```

If the call worked, then you'd have

```
$results = array();
$results['success'] = true;
$results['data'] = ....;
```

Comment: I agree with you! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I am sorry, but I strongly disagree with your understanding of HTTP status code. They very rarely say anything about the “HTTP calls themselves”. A 404, for example, explicitly says _the page was not found_, nothing to do with HTTP. Using HTTP status codes is both efficient and common for webservices. I use them all the times and much favor them over outputting text: they give a free standard for handling incorrect values, and make all tools understand something went wrong, as the question itself outlines.

Comment: @MattiSchneider-Ghibaudo-- thanks for the input. However, in the case described, where (for example) a record was not found, or maybe a DB error happened, how do you return meaningful information to the client via HTTP codes?

Comment: @julio your question made me decide to post a separate answer ;)

Comment: this is naive... coping with network lag or an unexpected reply, eg. 500 int server error, bad gateway, etc - will totally not reply. The onSuccess won't fire, the onComplete on a Request.JSON will not return an object and so on. Use onFailure & onSuccess. Period

Comment: @Dimitar: that's why there's an onfailure, to handle actual HTTP failures. If the requested script returns something, you get a 200 OK, and your onSuccess checks for the data['success'] flag.

Comment: @DimitarChristoff-- thanks for your input-- this may be best discussed in chat, but I'm with Marc on this. While I understand Matti's point and value the idea of using HTTP response codes, the question is still "How do you communicate application-level (not server level!) messages indicating "notice" rather than "fatal error" Eg. "no records found"? The app worked fine, the server worked fine, but we still must advise the client of a non-critical failure-- it seems returning a 40x/50x is not helpful.

Answer (score 3):

All answers given by @dombenoit and @Marc are technically correct.

However, I totally differ from @Marc's vision: to me, using HTTP status codes is both efficient and common for webservices. I use them all the times and much favor them over outputting text, mainly for the following reasons:

1. they give a free standard for handling incorrect values, instead of making you output text and parsing it clientside, meaning semantical repetition;
2. they make all tools understand something went wrong, as the question itself outlines;
3. they feel right in a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) architecture.

To support this vision, here's a question: what's the goal of your call? Is it to update or delete a record? Then if this goal is not reached, something went wrong. It failed, and the application should know it at application-level, not through first saying `200/OK` and then precising in the *textual* response it did not! To me, it feels like using `"undefined"` instead of `undefined`.

So, here, I would make PHP send an HTTP error status code, that is one in the `4xx`-`5xx` ranges.

---

Then, the good question is: **which code to use**? This is a design decision that totally depends on your application and the degree of specificity you want to get to.

- If the goal of the call is to update / delete, and the fact that it does not happen is extremely unlikely and is an **unexpected, serious error** (for example: the DB is inconsistent because there's no way the call could reference an entity that does not exist), then you should use `500 /  Internal Server Error`.
- If **it could be possible** that the targeted entity does not exist at the time of the call without it being a critical error (example: your app provides several ways to delete an item, so another one could have been used instead of this call), then I'd advise `410 / Gone`: you get a clear, expressive error handling, for free! And you can still use `500` for actual errors (DB connexion exceptions…).
- Then, you could get even more specific about update errors only, for example with `409 / Conflict` if that's the kind of errors you're trying to foresee with updates…

I always give a look at the [HTTP status codes reference](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) when I'm designing a webapp.

---

Just for the sake of completion, that's how you send headers in PHP (without framework at least — check for specificities):

```
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
```

---

**UPDATE**: since it seems you decided to go with the answer that suggested to use JSON to encode success or failure, I have to add the following points about resilience.

Not relying on status codes and only on application-level data makes your code very fragile. Indeed, there are situations where you get *actually unexpected* errors. Not the application-level “exception” that you raised yourself, but something wrong on a lower level (server unavailable, bad config that makes the server crash, changed routing system…). These will all show through HTTP status codes (or through timeout), but *not* through a JSON-encoded answer, since your application will have already crashed before being able to output anything.

Like @Dimitar put it, from a programming point of view, this is somehow “naive”: you trust not only your code (you shouldn't), but also the environment (server) and the network. That's a very, very optimistic vision.

Using status codes as the standard way to handle expected exceptional situations give you a free handling of those unexpected situations: you've already registered other handlers than `onSuccess`, and supposedly good ones (retrying once, notifying the user, offering backup possibilities…).

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment in order to avoid “ad placement” in an answer: just to show what's doable when respecting standards such as status codes, here is a MooTools class that provides [async form updates based on HTTP status codes](https://github.com/MattiSG/WebServiceForm) only. It has been of great use when developing frontends for webservices / API, as it makes the UI “understand” the status codes just like all other programming environments.

Comment: thank you very  much for a very thorough and well-thought out answer. It's very useful and has given me a lot to think about.

Comment: @julio Added some more (important) arguments. Thanks Dimitar for reminding me to explore this part! I might add another one later about performance and expand the one about maintainability, but don't have the time right now.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple options, two of which you mentionned in your question. You can use onSuccess and execute some code based on a true/false response, like so :

```
onSuccess: function(responseText, xml){
    if(responseText == "false"){
        // do something...
    }
}
```

Or you could raise errors in your PHP code, returning an actual valid error code thus firing the onFailure event.

Or as mentionned by Marc previously, you could use a JSON response format, in which case you would use MooTools' Request.JSON.

```
onSuccess: function(responseJSON, responseText){
    // do something...
}
```